# How to return value in ListViewAdapter

Tags: android

I started the Activity named CarrierSelectActivity using startActivityForResult method. and the activity has a ListView which is binded to CarrierSelectListAdapter.

I thought that just can solve using context.setResult(intent); but the context didn't have setResult() method

This is getView() in CarrierSelectListAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final int pos = position;
    final Context context = parent.getContext();

    // "listview_item" Layout을 inflate하여 convertView 참조 획득.
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_select_carriers, null);
    }

    // 화면에 표시될 View(Layout이 inflate된)으로부터 위젯에 대한 참조 획득
    ConstraintLayout layout = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_select_carrier);
    ImageView logo = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_select_carriers_logo);
    TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_select_carriers_carrierName);



    // Data Set(listViewItemList)에서 position에 위치한 데이터 참조 획득
    Carrier carrier = listViewItemList.get(position);

    // 아이템 내 각 위젯에 데이터 반영
    logo.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(context.getResources().getIdentifier(carrier.getLogo(), "drawable", context.getPackageName())));
    name.setText(carrier.getName());

    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("carrierName",);
            intent.putExtra("code");
            context.set         //HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Right, `setResult()` is a method of `Activity`, not of `Context`. Often, the ListAdapter is an inner class of an Activity, so it has access to `Activity.this`. Then you can call `Activity.this.setResult(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setResult()` is a method of `Activity`, not of `Context`. There are a couple of ways to get the Activity.

- Often, the ListAdapter is an inner class of an Activity, so it has access to `Activity.this`. Then you can call `Activity.this.setResult(...)`. So in your case, CarrierSelectListAdapter could be an inner class of CarrierSelectActivity, and your onClickListener could call `CarrierSelectActivity.this.setResult(...)`.
- Alternatively, you could pass the activity to the constructor of CarrierSelectListAdapter, which could assign it to a member variable `mActivity`. Then when you need to set the result, call `mActivity.setResult(...)`.